# pagination wrong progress of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, sites

This is my Code:

```
var pages = Math.ceil(allItems / itemsPerPage);
var pagesArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < pages; i++){
    pagesArray.push(i);
}
var show = 3;
var offset = pageCounter + show;
var showPages = pagesArray.slice(pageCounter, offset);
for(var h = 0; h < showPages.length; h++){
    if(pageCounter == showPages[h]){
        selectedPageClass = 'selected';
    }else{
        selectedPageClass = '';
    }
    $(".pagination").append("<a href='#' class='" + selectedPageClass +"'>" + showPages[h] + "</a>");
}
```

My Problem now is:
if I have this array `["1","2","3","4","5"]`

First Step when I am on page "0" it should be :

`1(selected) 2 3`

this works. but than it goes on like this:

`2(selected) 3 4`

`3(selected) 4 5`

`4(selected) 5`

`5(selected)`

But what I want is this:

`1(selected) 2 3`

`2(selected) 3 4`

`3(selected) 4 5`

`3 4(selected) 5`

`3 4 5(selected)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbBYva

You can update the variables on the top, the pageCounter is 0-based.

```
//editable variables
var pages = 5;
var pageCounter = 0;
var show = 3;

//calculation 
var pagesArray = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
    pagesArray.push(i);
}
var offset = pageCounter + show;
var showPages = pagesArray.slice(Math.min(pages - show, pageCounter), offset);
for(var h = 0; h < showPages.length; h++){
    if(pageCounter + 1 == showPages[h]){
        selectedPageClass = 'selected';
    }else{
        selectedPageClass = '';
    }
    $(".pagination").append("<a href='#' class='" + selectedPageClass +"'>" + showPages[h] + "</a>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do your `showPages` like this:

```
var showPages = pagesArray.slice(Math.min(pageCounter, pages- show), offset);
```

See demo below:

```js
var pages = 10,
  pageCounter = 0;
var pagesArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
  pagesArray.push(i);
}
var show = 3;

function paginate() {
  $(".pagination").empty();
  var offset = pageCounter + show;
  var showPages = pagesArray.slice(Math.min(pageCounter, pages - show), offset);

  for (var h = 0; h < showPages.length; h++) {
    if (pageCounter == showPages[h]) {
      selectedPageClass = 'selected';
    } else {
      selectedPageClass = '';
    }
    $(".pagination").append("<a href='#' class='" + selectedPageClass + "'>" + showPages[h] + "</a>");
  }
}

// initialize
paginate();

// turn pages
$('#counter').click(function() {
  if (pageCounter >= pages)
    return;
  pageCounter++;
  paginate();
});

// restart pagination
$('#restart').click(function() {
  pageCounter = 0;
  paginate();
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination"></div>
<button id="counter">Turn a page</button>
<button id="restart">Restart</button>
```